# ACCESS: variable text align based upon field length in Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I would like to have a text box change alignment on a Report based upon the length of the data contained.

For example:

If the length of Text is less than 100, then left justify.  If it is greater or equal to 100, then distribute...

Is this possible?

I am not expert at vba programming, so any help would me appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using vba by determining the alignment dependent on the length of the text. You could apply the same to any other property of your field as well

```
If Len(myfield) < 100 Then myfield.TextAlign = 1 Else myfield.TextAlign = 4
```

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/textbox-textalign-property-access) for further details.

Add this to the details section of the report, to apply the change to each and every single entry. For your approach, the final Sub should look like this:

```
Private Sub Detail_Paint()
If Len(CommRule) < 100 Then CommRule.TextAlign = 1 Else CommRule.TextAlign = 4
End Sub
```

In words: If the length of your CommRule value (the number of characters in your text) is smaller than 100 (then) set the alignment for CommRule to "left" (= 1), else set it to "distribute" (= 4)

Comment: I have added this to the Page() within the report, and it is not working.

Comment: If Len([CommRule]) < 100 Then [CommRule].TextAlign = 1 Else [CommRule].TextAlign = 4

Comment: Just tried it and it works perfectly fine for me.: If Len(CommRule) > 100 Then CommRule.TextAlign = 1 Else CommRule.TextAlign = 4 - though you need to add the line to the page() and load() event (otherwise it will not work on the startup-entry), insert a page break after each entry-footer and it only works in print preview

Comment: I'd say this rather belongs into the `<Section>_Format` event (e.g. `Detail_Format`)

Comment: It is changing the alignment on the string less than 100 to distribute.  I would like strings less than 100 to be left

Comment: Check that, it is changing all the text, regardless of length, to distribute

Comment: Maybe I should give a little more background....  CommRule is a field within a table, which has multiple rows.  The length of some CommRule fields are less than 100, and some are greater than 100.  Within my report, there are multiple rows of CommRule, which have varying field lengths.  I am wondering if this will only work if there is one CommRule field per report

Comment: Put the code in the `On Format` event of the Detail section, and it will apply to each row individually.

Comment: Good point, though use _Paint() instead.  @CPM: If you have 10 entries in your table, each of which has a CommRule with different length and you show all the entries on one page while using the suggested code in Detail_Paint(), each field will be formatted accordingly. If you also want a second field to be formatted, just add the same code to a new line and replace the fieldname.  'It is changing the alignment on the string less than 100 to distribute...'  Just turn the symbols around. I've edited the initial answer accordingly, though.

Comment: Actually, if you want it to work in both Print view/preview and Report view, you need to call the code in OnFormat **and** OnPaint events.

Comment: BAM!  @ThuroG & @Andre!  it worked!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there anyway to accomplish the same with a richText field?  When I attempted to use the VB provided on a rich text, Access locked up